# Multiple linear gradients with the same starting point

Tags: html, css, gradient

I'm trying to make multiple linear gradients on my application, and I want them to line up with the linear gradient in the parent. I tried searching around to figure out a solution, but I couldn't find anything related. Is there any way to achieve what I'm trying?

This is what it looks like

```css
main {
  --lin-grad-1: linear-gradient( 135deg, #f00 0%, #00f 100%)
}

main {
  position: relative;
  width: 700px;
  height: 400px;
  background: var(--lin-grad-1);
}

.test {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: var(--lin-grad-1);
}

.p1 {
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}

.p2 {
  top: 120px;
  left: 20px
}

.p3 {
  top: 70px;
  left: 250px;
}

.p4 {
  top: -50px;
  left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class='test p1' />
  <div class='test p2' />
  <div class='test p3' />
  <div class='test p4' />
</main>
```

This is what I want it to look like (while having the extra divs). I just removed the gradient from the divs, but for my usecase I need them, because those divs are blocking other divs behind them.

```css
main {
  --lin-grad-1: linear-gradient( 135deg, #f00 0%, #00f 100%)
}

main {
  position: relative;
  width: 700px;
  height: 400px;
  background: var(--lin-grad-1);
}

.test {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.p1 {
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}

.p2 {
  top: 120px;
  left: 20px
}

.p3 {
  top: 70px;
  left: 250px;
}

.p4 {
  top: -50px;
  left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class='test p1' />
  <div class='test p2' />
  <div class='test p3' />
  <div class='test p4' />
</main>
```

Comment: add `fixed` at the end of the gradient

Comment: Do you mean for the `<div>`s to be nested inside each other? Self-closing syntax does not work for them and the browser nests them inside each other. This will result in your examples looking different.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks Temani! If you would post it as an answer, I would gladly accept it.